# Conectar website con sql server 2008

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, odbc

estoy empezando a aprender un poco de programación, e intento hacer un registro que se conecte con un base de datos sql manager studio 2008 r2.
Todo va bien en cuanto al entorno local, el registro me funciona al igual que el sql, pero en cuanto subo el registro a un host web, deja de funcionar, me sale error de conexición y no entiendo por que puede ser, he revisado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido, puerto 1433, browser, las ip's firewall, puertos del pc, del router...
Por mi parte se me acabaron las ideas... Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor ^^
El registro lo tenia en odbc, pero me dijeron que esto daba error y ahora estoy usando mssql, si puedo elegir, prefiero odbc que ya tengo todo hecho en ese entorno.

Gracias por leer, un placer entrar a esta comunidad.
db.config.php

```
    <?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'test';
$dbPass = 'test123';
$GLOBALS['dbConn'] = @odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server={$GLOBALS['dbHost']};",$GLOBALS['dbUser'],$GLOBALS['dbPass']) or die('Database Connection Error!');
if(!$GLOBALS['dbConn']){
    exit("Connection failed:".odbc_errormsg());
}
?>
```

register.php

```
    <?php
require_once('db.config.php');
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : '';
$password2 = isset($_POST['password2']) ? trim($_POST['password2']) : '';
$nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? trim($_POST['nombre']) : '';
$apellidos = isset($_POST['apellidos']) ? trim($_POST['apellidos']) : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : '';
$patron = isset($_POST['patron']) ? trim($_POST['patron']) : '';
$errors = array();
$success = false;
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    if(empty($username)){
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a user name.';
    }else if(strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16){
        $errors[] = 'User name must be between 3 and 16 characters in length.';
    }else if(ctype_alnum($username) === false){
        $errors[] = 'User name must consist of numbers and letters only.';
    }else{
        // Check if username already exists in the database.
        $sql = "SELECT UserID FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master WHERE UserID = ?";
        $stmt = odbc_prepare($GLOBALS['dbConn'],$sql);
        $args = array($username);
        if(!odbc_execute($stmt,$args)){
            $errors[] = 'Failed to determine if this username already exists in the database.';
        }elseif($row = odbc_fetch_array($stmt)){
            $errors[] = 'User name already exists, please choose a different user name.';
        }
    }
    if(empty($password)){
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a password.';
    }else if(strlen($password) < 3 || strlen($password) > 16){
        $errors[] = 'Password must be between 3 and 16 characters in length.';
    }else if($password != $password2){
        $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match.';
    }
    if(count($errors) == 0){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master
                (UserID,Pw,JoinDate,Admin,AdminLevel,UseQueue,Status,Leave,LeaveDate,UserType,Point,EnPassword,UserIp,nombre,apellidos,email,patron)
                VALUES (?,?,GETDATE(),0,0,0,0,0,GETDATE(),'N',0,'',?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = odbc_prepare($GLOBALS['dbConn'],$sql);
        $args = array($username,$password,$user_ip,$nombre,$apellidos,$email,$patron);
        if(odbc_execute($stmt,$args)){
            $success = htmlentities("Account {$username} successfully created!");
        }else{
            $errors[] = 'Failed to create a new account, please try again later';
        }
    }
}
if($success === false){
    require_once('register.view.php');
}else{
    require_once('success.view.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código que tengas. Tal y como está ahora, lo más que te vamos a poder sugerir son suposiciones.

Comment: db.config.php
https://pastebin.com/LPRZXwp4
register.php
https://pastebin.com/QDUeq5wu
También me han comentado que desde ese código me pueden hacer inyecciones, ¿alguna recomendación?